Understanding Layer Values in JLayeredPane: Determining the Range for pane.add() Parameters
What's the biggest and smallest number that can be used in: pane.add() ?
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JLayeredPane pane = new JLayeredPane();
        pane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        pane.setBackground(Color.pink);
        pane.setOpaque(true);

        JPanel blueBox = new JPanel();
        blueBox.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
        blueBox.setBackground(Color.BLUE);

        JPanel redBox = new JPanel();
        redBox.setBounds(150,100,100,100);
        redBox.setBackground(Color.RED);


        pane.add(blueBox, Integer.valueOf(-948884));
        pane.add(redBox, Integer.valueOf(1009499595));


        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(pane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
}

I read the docs but didn't find the answer: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JLayeredPane.html
My guess is: the smallest number is the smallest int number and the largest is the biggest int number but i want to be sure 

Since the documentation doesn’t mention any limits, I would assume any integer value is valid for a layer number.

To put a panel into a JFrame should be
If you want to Z order stack A.K.A Panels inside the JFrames' contentpane.
NOTE: the internal Panel all JFrame contain is actually a "Component"
Layered pane contains as many Component layers as are placed into the JLayeredPane.
Layers should not be confused with "position" of which either are numbered from first or lowest layer "0" to last and top most layer (the number of layers inserted to the JLayeredPane minus one).
highestLayer() method of JLayeredPane will bring back the index number of the top most layer panel inserted not the position depth. See JLayeredPane setPosition(Component c, int position) in the API docs
Using swing always requires use of java.awt.Component and java.awt.Container that are part of the "extended hierarchy" of every javax.swing class!
   // frame.getContentPane().add(panel0,-1); 
// z order bottom most
// This however does not get anything more than the default JFrame panel

// If you want to add a stack of 25 panels starting with last
Component[] layercomponent = new Component[25];
JLayeredPane jlayerpane = frame.getLayeredPane();

for(int cm = 0; cm < 25; cm++){
// do not forget to size your components and give them a layout or they cannot be visible
layercomponent[cm] = new JPanel();
layercomponent[cm].setSize(1024,768);
} //enfr

for(int av = 0; av < 25; av++){
jlayerpane.add(layercomponent[av],av);
}
    
    // Component frame.getGlassPane() NOTE Container "extends" //Component

// glass pane (its primary reason of use) is for having a transparent layer pane always over the top to specially screen mouse events with cursor position.
    Container framecontainer = frame.getContentPane(); this is the normal way to get the default panel box from a swing JFrame , not make one.
    // more of a note
    int totalPanels = framecontainer.getComponentCount();


This does not answer the question.
